# Meaning and usage of the word meme in a technical context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-usage, programming

I have been dabbling in meaning of words and I was wondering about the possible usage of the word `meme` in English which started in Greek `mimeme`.

Google gives me the definition:

> An element of a culture or system of behaviour passed from one individual to another by imitation or other non-genetic means

and somewhere else I get:

> Something imitated

I would like to use the word in the context of programming because of our nature of imitating older languages when we create new ones.

My current elaboration of the word is: *"That which is imitated from language to language. e.g.: loops and control statements"*

Currently used in: *"What are the most iconic programming memes and do they have an idiomatic representation?"*

Comment: Given the current usage of the word *meme*, I don't recommend using it in a technical sense.

Comment: Would 'legacy' be a good alternative with rephrasing of the sentence it is used in? Maybe even the elaboration it self.

Comment: What is the sentence it is used in? Add it to the OP and I can tell you.

Comment: @Hank I have added it to the post. Possible alternation could be "What are the most iconic programming legacies and do they have an idiomatic representation?"

Comment: My research is about idiomacy in programming languages. Just like English or any other human language has idioms the programming languages also have them.

Comment: @MarkHubbard I don't think his use of idiomatic has any effect on his word choice earlier in the sentence. To me, an understanding of what he means by idiomatic will be explained in whatever research paper he publishes.

Comment: Thank you, Adrian and Hank. *"What are the most iconic programming memes and do they have an idiomatic representation?"* It's a *beautiful* sentence, in my opinion, but I don't quite get the distinction. Can you provide an example of a programming meme and its idiomatic representation? I'm not criticizing your word choices; I just don't get what an answer to that question might look like.

Comment: @MarkHubbard an example of a programming meme could be a statement which repeats it self between languages e.g.: a while statement or a variable assignment. Why do we do it this way and not some other way? It's because we trust in the ways that they have been developed and the thought process behind them. It probably also has something do to with us being easily biased about something what we use day-in and day-out. All of those things have some kind of idiomatic representation in some language but not in all. Easiest examples would probably be python and its pythonic way http://bit.ly/1Q8fU4q

Comment: Thanks, Adrian! I'm always glad to learn something new. :-)

Comment: The word 'meme' is rapidly evolving and will mean different thing to different people at this time.  People are using the complex and interesting term to refer to something as simple as a photo with humorous text put atop it.  I suppose a large percentage of words have mutiple meanings though

Comment: Richard Dawkins has been given credit to giving (new?)life to the term in the 1970's.  Interesting(light, not comprehensive) read for those interested... http://www.wired.co.uk/article/richard-dawkins-memes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Legacy***, in the computer world, is usually used to describe something that is outdated. I wouldn't recommend using that. Perhaps ***standards*** or ***statements*** will work in your example:

> #### Standard
>
> - Something established by authority, custom, or general consent as a model or example; a criterion.
>
> *"What are the most iconic programming **standards** and do they have an idiomatic representation?"*

([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/standard))

> #### Statement
>
> - An instruction in a computer program
>
> *"What are the most iconic programming **statements** and do they have an idiomatic representation?"*

([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/statement))

They don't necessarily carry the concept of being handed down or mimicked, per se, but they carry the idea that it is universally used across all programming.

Comment: You're right about the legacy. I'm not sure if the term 'standard' fully grasps what I want to say.

Comment: In case of 'convention' it probably will have to many question marks around it. Meaning of it is probably to broad.

Comment: 'Statement' would probably represent what I would like to convey. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statement_(computer_science). "What are the most iconic programming statements and do they have an idiomatic representation?"

Comment: Sound good! Thanks for your help! I'll mark is as the answer.

Comment: I think missing the definition of a meme being an idea with a life of it's own misses the more interesting definition of the word, even if more simple definitions are used now.

Comment: @Tom22 Nothing was missed. But it still doesn't change the fact that, in society's current state, the usage of meme will be confusing to contemporary readers.